# React useCallback function runs in infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet-geoman

I am trying to use [leaflet-geoman](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman) library in a React project. I need to create a custom toolbar button that enables and disables global [drag mode](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman#drag-mode).

When toolbar button is clicked, `map.pm.enableGlobalDragMode();` function enables global mode. When toolbar button is clicked again, `map.pm.disableGlobalDragMode();` causes useCallback function `afterClick` running in infinite loop.

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-thunder-kts3n?file=/src/useDraw.js)

**useDraw.js**

```
import React from "react";

const useDraw = (mapRef) => {
  const afterClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log("afterclick");
    const map = mapRef.current.leafletElement;
    let editDragEnabled = false;
    if (!editDragEnabled) {
      console.log("enable");
      map.pm.enableGlobalDragMode();
      editDragEnabled = true;
    } else {
      console.log("disable");
      map.pm.disableGlobalDragMode();
      editDragEnabled = false;
    }
  }, [mapRef]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const map = mapRef.current.leafletElement;

    var actions = ["finishMode"];
    map.pm.addControls({
      drawRectangle: false,
      drawMarker: false,
      drawPolyline: false,
      drawPolygon: false,
      drawCircle: false,
      drawCircleMarker: false,
      removalMode: false,
      editMode: false,
      cutPolygon: false,
      dragMode: false
    });
    map.pm.Toolbar.createCustomControl({
      name: "DragEdit",
      block: "custom",
      title: "Edit and Drag Layers",
      onClick: () => afterClick(),
      actions: actions,
      toggle: true
    });
  }, [mapRef, afterClick]);
};

export default useDraw;
```

Comment: Why you want to create a new drag button instead of overwriting the existing one? What do you want to customize?

Comment: @FalkeDesign enabling/disabling dragging and editing all geometries together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that when `enableGlobalDragMode` ( or disable) the Control of the original drag button is activated and this disables your custom button (because all other buttons are disabled, so that only one mode can be active).

I suggest to use the code from the `enableGlobalDragMode` function instead of calling it, which cause a change on the controls:

```
const afterClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log("afterclick");
    const map = mapRef.current.leafletElement;

    const layers = L.PM.Utils.findLayers(map);
    let dragMode = map.pm._customModeEnabled || false;
    if(!dragMode){
      console.log("enable");
      layers.forEach((layer)=>{
        layer.pm.enableLayerDrag();
      })
    }else{
      console.log("disable");
      layers.forEach((layer)=>{
        layer.pm.disableLayerDrag();
      })
    }
    map.pm._customModeEnabled = !dragMode;
  }, [mapRef]);
```